# Android location mode, no GPS, options in AOSP

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-source, android-location

I'm working on an Android M STB without a GPS chip. In Android settings, Location, I get three choices for Location support -- High Accuracy, Low Bat, GPS Only. The system is defaulting to High Accuracy mode.

The problem here is that when wifi.getScanResults() is called from a background service and one of the location modes needing GPS is enabled, I don't get any results back. The call works fine from a foreground app, only background services are impacted by this. When I change the system over to Location mode Low Bat (which does not require GPS) the background getScanResults() call works as expected.

How do I modify my AOSP build so that the High Accuracy and GPS Only choices won't be presented to the user since there is no GPS chip?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the `LocationManagerService` class so it doesn't load a GPS provider? The following might be what you are looking for.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/nougat-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java#L453

Answer (score 0):

The default location mode is set by `def_location_providers_allowed` in [`frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r81/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml#46). Its value can be either `gps` (GPS only), `network` (Battery saving) or `gps,network` (High accuracy).

You could therefore set `def_location_providers_allowed` to `network` (e.g. in a device/vendor overlay) and disable or hide the *Mode* option to the user in *Settings* → *Location* since you have only one choice (see [`packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/location_mode.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-6.0.1_r81/res/xml/location_mode.xml)).